# Decoding / Encloding Text File using Stack Library - Can't Encode Large Files C++

Tags: c++, file-io, encoding, stack, decoding

I am working on a program that can encode and then decode text in C++.  I am using the stack library.  The way the program works is that it first asks you for a cypher key, which you put in manually.  It then asks for the file name, which is a text file. If it is a normal txt file, it encodes the message to a new file and adds a .iia files extension. If the text file already has a .iia file extension, then it decodes the message, as long as the cypher key is the same as the one used to encode it.

My program does encode and decode, but how many characters it decodes is determined by `temp.size() % cypher.length()` that is in the while loop in the `readFileEncode()` function.  I think this is what is keeping the entire file from being encoded and then decoded correctly. Another words, the ending file after it has been decoded from say "example.txt.iia" back to "example.txt" is missing a large portion of the text from the original "example.txt" file.  I tried just `cypher.length()` but of course that does not encode or decode anything then. The entire process is determined by that argument for the decoding and encoding.

I cannot seem to find out the exact logic for this to encode and decode all the characters in any size file.  Here is the following code for the function that does the decoding and encoding:

EDIT: Using WhozCraig's code that he edited for me:

```
void readFileEncode(string fileName, stack<char> &text, string cypher)
{
    std::ifstream file(fileName, std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);
    stack<char> temp;
    char ch;

    while (file.get(ch))
        temp.push(ch ^ cypher[temp.size() % cypher.length()]);

    while (!temp.empty())
    {
        text.push(temp.top());
        temp.pop();
    }
}
```

EDIT: A stack is required.  I am going to implement my own stack class, but I am trying to get this to work first with the stack library.  Also, if there is a better way of implementing this, please let me know. Otherwise, I believe that there is not much wrong with this except to get it to go through the loop to encode and decode the entire file. I am just unsure as to why it stops at, say 20 characters sometimes, or ten characters. I know it has to do with how long the cypher is too, so I believe it is in the % (mod). Just not sure how to rewrite.

EDIT: Ok, tried WhozCraig's solution and I don't get the desired output, so the error now must be in my main.  Here is my code for the main:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip> 
#include <fstream>
#include <string> 
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>
#include <stack>


using namespace std;

void readFileEncode(string fileName, stack<char> &text, string cypher);

int main()
{
    stack<char> text;   // allows me to use stack from standard library
    string cypher;
    string inputFileName;
    string outputFileName;
    int position;

    cout << "Enter a cypher code" << endl;
    cin >> cypher;
    cout << "Enter the name of the input file" << endl;
    cin >> inputFileName;

    position = inputFileName.find(".iia");//checks to see if the input file has the iia extension

    if (position > 1){
        outputFileName = inputFileName;
        outputFileName.erase(position, position + 3);// if input file has the .iia extension it is erased 
    }
    else
        //outputFileName.erase(position, position + 3);// remove the .txt extension and
        outputFileName = inputFileName + ".iia";// add the .iia extension to file if it does not have it

    cout << "Here is the new name of the inputfile " << outputFileName << endl; // shows you that it did actually put the .iia on or erase it depending on the situation

    system("pause");

    readFileEncode(inputFileName, text, cypher); //calls function            

    std::ofstream file(outputFileName); // calling function

    while (text.size()){// goes through text file
        file << text.top();
        text.pop(); //clears pop
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Basically, I am reading .txt file to encrypt and then put a .iia file extension on the filename.  Then I go back through, enter the file back with the .iia extension to decode it back.  When I decode it back it is gibberish after about the first ten words.

@WhozCraig Does it matter what white space, newlines, or punctuation is in the file? Maybe with the full solution here you can direct me at what is wrong.

Comment: I *know* there is a reason you're not using a `queue` or `deque` for this. I just know it... Its the *why not* that still eludes me.

Comment: Using a stack is required.  I am using the library now, but will probably build my own stack class in the end.

Comment: Do you have to use a stack for *both*, or is just the reference parameter sufficient? Not that it will necessarily cut down on your performance (which can be considerably improved, and I'll post an answer if I get a chance).

Comment: @WhozCraig Both? I am not sure what you mean. Are you talking about just storing the pointer on the stack? I am actually trying to take the advice of user2445771 and just use strings right now. I will update that code when I can.  I am trying to turn this around the best I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you want the entire file rotationally XOR'd with  the chars in the cipher key. If that is the case, you can probably address your immediate error by simply doing this:

```
void readFileEncode(string fileName, stack<char> &text, string cypher)
{
    std::ifstream file(fileName, std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);
    stack<char> temp;
    char ch;

    while (file.get(ch))
        temp.push(ch ^ cypher[temp.size() % cypher.length()]);

    while (!temp.empty())
    {
        text.push(temp.top());
        temp.pop();
    }
}
```

The most notable changes are

- Opening the file in binary-mode using `std::ios::in|std::ios::binary` for the open-mode. this will eliminate the need to invoke the `noskipws` manipulator (which is *usually* a function call) for every character extracted.
- Using `file.get(ch)` to extract the next character. The member will pull the next char form the file buffer directly if one is available, otherwise load the next buffer and try again.

---

**Alternative**

A character by character approach is going to be expensive any way you slice it. That this is going through a `stack<>`, which will be backed by a `vector` or `deque` isn't going to do you any favors. That it is going through *two* of them just compounds the agony. You may as well load the whole file in one shot, compute all the XOR's directly, then push them on to you stack via a reverse iterator:

```
void readFileEncode
(
    const std::string& fileName,
    std::stack<char> &text,
    const std::string& cypher
)
{
    std::ifstream file(fileName, std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);

    // retrieve file size
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    std::istream::pos_type pos = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    // early exit on zero-length file.
    if (pos == 0)
        return;

    // make space for a full read
    std::vector<char> temp;
    temp.resize(static_cast<size_t>(pos));
    file.read(temp.data(), pos);

    size_t c_len = cypher.length();
    for (size_t i=0; i<pos; ++i)
        temp[i] ^= cypher[i % c_len];

    for (auto it=temp.rbegin(); it!=temp.rend(); ++it)
        text.push(*it);
}
```

You still get your stack on the caller-side, but I think you'll be considerably happier with the performance.

Comment: Thank you by the way for taking so much time to post this!

Comment: Your notable changes make sense. I understand why to use file.get(ch). However this solution did not work still. It decodes back the first 10 or so words, then everything else after that is gibberish still. Not sure why. I am looking at it now. The only reason why I won't use the alternative method is because I haven't gone over vectors and some of the functions and other things that you are using. I want to be able to understand the solution totally, and I have to say that the alternative is over my head a bit.

Comment: I've tested both solutions against a 100MB (exactly) file and the results are exactly as I would expect them to be. And in fact, dumping the stack into another file and repeating the procedure yields the first file as a result, which would be entirely expected. I'm not sure what toolchain and system you're doing this on, but as-written both should work.

Comment: Edited my post. Must be something in my main then. Now the full code is attached to the post. Thank you again, hopefully you can point out what I am missing then, because I thought my main was pretty straight forward. My goal is to adapt this into a argc & argv implementation. I am just trying to get it to work as it is though.

Comment: Does it matter what my cypher is? I am just trying to narrow it down. I am using a five letter work for my cypher.

Comment: it shouldn't matter what the cipher is, so long as it has *length*. (i.e. passing an empty string would not be good). So long as you use the same symmetric password for both encr and decr it should be fine.

Comment: Ok. I just checked your output file code, and you should *not* be using the stream insertion operator. using the code I have above you should be opening the output file with mode `std::ios::out | std::ios::binary` and using `file.put(text.top());`. Give that a try.

Comment: Oh geez. So simple. I have been looking at this too long. I should have been able to eyeball that after seeing it in the `readFileEncode()` function in the ifstream. Again, makes sense after you point out what is right in front of your face. Wish I had your talent. Thanks for all the help. This sets me up good to right my stack classes and argc main. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

just for information: never read file char by char it will take you hours to finish 100Mb.
read at least 512 byte(in my case i read directly 1 or 2Mb ==> store in char * and then process).